# RegExp trouble with a LONG pattern

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, replace, preg-replace

Usually the string is long and the pattern is short when doing a Reqular Expression code, but this time is the other way around. I have a short text of about 500 characters. In that text I want to find names that match a database of about 47.000 unique names and add a link to the specific name. What is the best way of doing this? I partition the array of names into 64 partitions since the one array is to big to procces as a pattern.

```
function implode_r ($glue, $pieces){
    $out = "";
    foreach ($pieces as $piece){
        if (is_array ($piece)){
            $out .= implode_r ($glue, $piece); // recurse
        }
        else{
            if(strlen($piece)>1){
                $piece = str_replace("(", "\(", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace(")", "\)", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("[", "\[", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("]", "\]", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace(":", "\:", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace(".", "\.", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace(",", "\,", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("'", "\'", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("&", "\&", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("?", "\?", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("!", "\!", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("&lt;", "\&lt;", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("&gt;", "\&gt;", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("{", "\{", $piece);
                $piece = str_replace("}", "\}", $piece);
                $out .= $glue.$piece;
            }
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

function partition( $list, $p ) {
    $listlen = count( $list );
    $partlen = floor( $listlen / $p );
    $partrem = $listlen % $p;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for ($px = 0; $px &lt; $p; $px++) {
        $incr = ($px &lt; $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$px] = array_slice( $list, $mark, $incr );
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    return $partition;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'find_names_in_text');
add_filter( 'get_the_content', 'find_names_in_text');
function find_names_in_text($content){
    global $wpdb;
    $thenames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='dogs' GROUP BY post_title", ARRAY_N);
    $namesparts = partition($thenames, 64);
    foreach($namesparts as $part){
        $pattern = implode_r("|", $part);
        $content = preg_replace("(".$pattern.")", "&lt;a href='$1'&gt;$1&lt;/a&gt;", $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Side note, you could use arrays in `str_replace()` like `str_replace(array('a', 'b'), array('c', 'd'), $input);`

Answer (score 3):

If your text is only 500 characters, i'd go about it the other way around. Divide the text in parts that could be a name (assuming those are words, no split-word names I presume).

So now you have < 500 words you want to match in your database, so worst case you have to check your database for those. You won't get 500 words ofcourse out of 500 characters, so you'd get a manageable query from there.

Comment: Thanks! Now the problem is to split the text in to possible names since all the names has more than one word in them. Here's an example of what I need to get out of the code, but with just the matching names in the pattern.

http://regexr.com?3787i

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame, but not impossible to do: with something like a sliding/moving window algorithm you should theoritically be able to split the character set into various multiple word groups, and check those against the database. You would get more queries, but with 500 characters this wouldn't be too much probably?